# How to disable link/button/etc when last item is visible in a carousel in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I've built a carousel but I want the buttons to be disabled when the last/first item is in the viewport, i.e. when the last item is visible then disable the 'next' button.
I'm using `unbind('click')` but it doesn't work.

Please show me the way.

JS:

```
var MYPROJECT = {
CONTROL: '.controls',
SLIDELIST: '.slide-wrapper ul',

init: function(){
    this.projectCarousel();
},

projectCarousel: function(){
    var self = this,
        jqs_slideList = $(self.SLIDELIST),
        slide = jqs_slideList.find('.slide'),
        slideWidth = jqs_slideList.find('.slide').outerWidth(true),
        firstSlidePos = slide.first().position().left,
        lastSlidePos = slide.last().position(),
        count = 0;

    $(this.CONTROL).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        var thisElm = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();

        if (thisElm.hasClass('prev')) {/* if prev button is clicked */

            jqs_slideList.animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + slideWidth + 'px' });

        } else if (thisElm.hasClass('next')) {/* if next button is clicked */

            jqs_slideList.animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + slideWidth + 'px' });

            count++;

            if (count === (slide.length - 1)) {

                // disable button
                thisElm.unbind('click').css({ /* this should be in css class */
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        cursor: 'default'
                    });
            } 
        }
    });
}
};

MYPROJECT.init();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" class="prev">-</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">+</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 1)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>

        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 2)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
  margin: 45px auto 0;
  width: 318px;
}

.slideshow .slide-wrapper {
width:325px;
padding: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow ul {
width: 696px;
}

.slideshow .slide {
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
}

.slideshow .slide article {
background: #fff;
bottom: 0px;
box-shadow: -2px -1px 8px #bbb;
padding: 10px;
width: 298px;
z-index: 5;
}

.controls {
position: relative;
top: 150px;
}

.controls a {
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 65px;
position: absolute;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 65px;
}

.controls .prev {
left: -115px;
}

.controls .next {
right: -115px;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use some other means to check where you are in your carousel. For instance, you could use the [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) from your list instead.

The best way to disable your buttons is by checking the current slide index, and add a disabled class to the control and only animate depending on

- Prev: `$(".slide").index() > 0`
- Next: `$(".slide").index() < $(".slide-wrapper ul").index() < $(".slide").index()`

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHza/2/) I made for you. There's also a [how to create your own plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) that might be good to take into consideration in your project. Just giving you a push in the right direction, good luck!

Here's the code

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.projectCarousel = function(){
        var $slides = $(".slide", this),
            $current_slide = $(".slide:first-child", this),
            $prev = $(".controls a.prev", this),
            $next = $(".controls a.next", this);

        if($current_slide.index() <= 0) $prev.addClass("disabled");

        $prev.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if($current_slide.index() > 0){
                if($prev.hasClass("disabled")) $prev.removeClass("disabled");
                $(".slide-wrapper ul").animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + $current_slide.outerWidth(true)+ 'px' });
                $current_slide = $current_slide.prev();
            }

            if($current_slide.index() <= 0){
                //disable previous
                $prev.addClass("disabled");
                $next.removeClass("disabled");
            }
        });

        $next.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if($current_slide.index() < $slides.index()){
                if($next.hasClass("disabled")) $next.removeClass("disabled");
                $(".slide-wrapper ul").animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + $current_slide.outerWidth(true)+ 'px' });
                $current_slide = $current_slide.next();
            }

            if($current_slide.index() >= $slides.index()){
                //disable next
                $next.addClass("disabled");
                $prev.removeClass("disabled");
            }
        });

    }
})( jQuery );

$(".slideshow").projectCarousel();
```

---

### Array based

Another way is to store each slide element in an array. This approach is very efficient and reliable. The main downside of this approach is that it's a memory hog, but shouldn't be a problem unless you've got alot of slides. It's also very useful, since you can decide which slide # you want to jump to.

An example of an array-based carousel could be done like in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSNaK/).

Basically, all the animations are contained within one function `_to_slide(index)` that takes one argument: "Which frame should I animate to?". Since the array is number based, it is more easily managable and controllable.

Here's the code (Including html and css, changed some to accomodate more functions)

Javascript

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.projectCarousel = function(){
        var $slides = $(".slide", this),
            $current_slide = $(".slide:first-child", this),
            $prev = $(".controls a.prev", this),
            $next = $(".controls a.next", this);

        if($current_slide.index() <= 0) $prev.addClass("disabled");

        $prev.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if($current_slide.index() > 0){
                if($prev.hasClass("disabled")) $prev.removeClass("disabled");
                $(".slide-wrapper ul").animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + $current_slide.outerWidth(true)+ 'px' });
                $current_slide = $current_slide.prev();
            }

            if($current_slide.index() <= 0){
                //disable previous
                $prev.addClass("disabled");
                $next.removeClass("disabled");
            }
        });

        $next.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if($current_slide.index() < $slides.index()){
                if($next.hasClass("disabled")) $next.removeClass("disabled");
                $(".slide-wrapper ul").animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + $current_slide.outerWidth(true)+ 'px' });
                $current_slide = $current_slide.next();
            }

            if($current_slide.index() >= $slides.index()){
                //disable next
                $next.addClass("disabled");
                $prev.removeClass("disabled");
            }
        });

    }
})( jQuery );

$(".slideshow").projectCarousel();
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" class="start"><-</a>
    <a href="#" class="prev">-</a>
    <input class='select' type='text' value='1' />
    <a href="#" class="next">+</a>
    <a href="#" class="end">-></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 1)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>

        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 2)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 3)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 4)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 5)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <article>
                <h3>Some title here (nav 6)</h3>
                <p>Over the past few years, mobile web usage has considerably increased.</p>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {
      margin: 45px auto 0;
      width: 318px;
}

.slideshow .slide-wrapper {
    width:325px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow ul {
    width: 2088px;
}

.slideshow .slide {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.slideshow .slide article {
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: -2px -1px 8px #bbb;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 298px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.controls {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}

.controls a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}

input.select{
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

a.disabled{
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

---

If you're interested in some theory behind the subject, you could read up on them
[linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) vs [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) vs [deques](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/).

Even though most of the links are to C++ libraries, the theory is sound for all programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than unbinding the click, try the following:

```
        if (count === (slide.length - 1)) {
            // disable button
            thisElm.addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            thisElm.removeClass('disabled');
        }
```

Then, inside the main `.on('click'...)` event handler, you'd check for the `disabled` class before anything else:

```
$(this.CONTROL).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    var thisElm = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!thisElm.hasClass('disabled'){
        //do the rest inside here
    }
});
```

Comment: I do like this approach much better than constantly binding/unbinding.

Comment: @maxedison: Thanks for your response. So in the class `disabled', how would you cancel the animation to carry on? Because for the moment the carousel still continues when the last item is visible. This is where I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

Without a namesapce you need to pass in the function in order to unbind so you either need to make you function into a call back and pass that in as the second arg to `unbind` Or you can use a namespace like `carousel.click` and then just unbind that namespace.